# programmatically set layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I've created four folders for different layouts, to make my app support all screens. Four folders, namely, layout(By Default), layout-large, layout-small, layout-xlarge, i've created. Inside all of them, i've put an xml file that has same name "activity_start.xml". Now, i want to set the layout programmatically  using following code in my startActivity.java:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

    switch(displayMetrics.densityDpi)
    { 
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:

            // layout for small sized devices.

            break; 

        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM: 

            // layout for medium-sized devices.
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
            break; 

        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH: 

            // layout for big-sized devices.
            setContentView(R.layout-large.activity_start);//<----------- syntax error in this line
            break; 
    }
```

Now in the case for **DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM**, the code is correct(I guess), but when i do setContentView for **DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH** it does not take the folder i created(layout-large).

I mean, when we type in arguments for setContentView, typing R.lay...(hit ctrl+space), it does not show the folder "layout-large".

I want to set layout programmatically. If anyone could help me, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this entirely wrong. The whole point of having the qualified folder names is to avoid having to handle it programmatically altogether. Android handles this automatically. Also, density is not equivalent to screen size, so your attempt to tie densities to the different screen size layouts is incorrect.

If there is no major difference between the layouts for the different screen sizes (and really, there *shouldn't* be other than for tablet-type layouts (layout-sw600dp or layout-sw720dp) you should use the fewest number of layouts possible to accomplish your design.